# Wordpress TinyMCE not working for chrome browser

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have serious problem in wordpress tiny mce editor. TinyMCE work fine in firefox, but it not working on chrome and chromium browser. I try to find any javascript error but i am not able to find. My wordpress version : 2.8.6 and Tiny MCE Version 3.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

this might be due to not loading of tinymce javascript. try to check your page souce by pressing ctrl+u on chrome browser.

Comment: The problem is, when we try to edit post and change there words to bold or italic its not working when we add new post its work fine.